# What should I do when my database is too huge and I need all the data initially at the frontend

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, optimization, web-applications

I use Mongodb and my collection has gotten very huge. It contains 15k documents and it's size is almost 15 mb. The website I am working on uses a map and shows every element on the map. This design of the website makes it hard to paginate. Whenever I make a request to my express backend, it gives me error about the javascript heap out of memory.[This is that error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LTkz.png)

What can I do to make sure my website still works while keeping these things in mind:

1. My database is too huge
2. My website doesn't allow pagination
3. If I keep using the current design my backend crashes

I'm sorry if I am being stupid or something, this is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow

Comment: Judging from your screenshot, you are using Heroku. They should be able to handle 15mb of data without a problem. There is likely something else going on. But pushing 15mb to the client is a bad idea regardless of the backend anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do pagination, but still load the data incrementally, and visualize it as it arrives. Think of it as a loading animation.

Step 1: Load app, display the map without data
Step 2: As the data arrives in chunks render it.

Or use something like websocket.

Find a way to hash/paginate it, even if you use something stupid like first character of the ID to do it

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try implementing this and see how it goes

Comment: I was finally able to implement this, I used a library called supercluster which is blazing fast. I was able to cluster all my tags and then get then using a websocket connection whenever user dragged the map around.